# How to turn off the stats displayed when playing a game?

Tags: game-engine

[image]

These statistics are displayed when I play the game in the game engine. How do I turn these off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either disable it with python:

```
bpy.context.scene.game_settings.show_framerate_profile = False
```

or untick the checkbox in the render settings panel:

[image]